# Question about checkbox and datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

I have datagridview with checkbox column, and the checkbox within the column can be checked or unchecked with external checkbox. It works fine while selecting all the columns and saving the data in database. But, when I unchecked the checkbox in the datagridview with external checkbox and again select the single checkbox within the datagridview, it again takes the rowindex of all the checkbox within the column.

```
if (chkbranches.Checked == true)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in gridviewholiday.Rows)
  {
    dr.Cells[0].Value = true;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < gridviewholiday.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    rowindex = i;
    list.add(rowindex);//to put the rowindex in array list
  }
}
else if (chkbranches.Checked == false)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in gridviewholiday.Rows)
  {
    dr.Cells[0].Value = false;
    gridviewholiday.Refresh();
    gridviewholiday.ClearSelection();
    list.Clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the code to select/unselect all checkboxes, which you said works correctly? What we'd need is to code when you select a single checkbox in the DataGridView...

Comment: Where have you written this code (which event), also you should mark as answer for your previous questions where you found a satisfactory response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you loop twice if chkbranches is checked? Can't you add items to the list within the first foreach? And in the loop for unchecking, why do you refresh, and clear both controls each time? Probably only needed once.

And as mentioned, this isn't doing anything about single checks. If you're expecting it to, that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your attempting to do, but I have something similar with a button that deletes all the checked rows.  I use a template field like so for the check box:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelector" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then for the Delete button code behind I do:

```
protected void btnDeleteChecked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridOrders.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbSelector");
        if ((null != cb) && cb.Checked)
        {
            uint id = Convert.ToUInt32(gridOrders.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
            gInvoiceDB.DeleteInvoice(id, true);
        }
    }
}
```